# Use a variable and a text string as a key in liquid shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

In my Shopify theme I wish to display the value of a metafield. The key for this metafield is the string "prod_" joined with the product type.

Let's imagine that the product is a *sofa*. I can display the value of this metafield by simply using the metafield's name as a text string.

```
   {{product.metafields.global["prod__sofa"]}}
```

I however wish to replace the "sofa" part of the string with the value of the field.

To do this I can create a variable called "type"

```
   {% assign type = product.type %}
```

I am now however finding it difficult to use the variable "type" and the text string to look up the metafield.

My issue is in joining them together, I have used both a "+" and "&", but this does not work.

```
{{product.metafields.global["prod__" & type]}}
{{product.metafields.global["prod__" & type]}}
```

Am I joining the variable and string together incorrectly or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is wrong `{{product.metafields.global["prod__" & type]}}`.

You can't concatenate strings that way.

You should generate the string before hand and use the ready string:

```
{% assign type = product.type | prepend: 'prod_' %}
{{product.metafields.global[type]}}
```

or

```
{%- capture type -%}type_{{product.type}}{%- endcapture -%}
{{product.metafields.global[type]}}
```